# react timeline calendar items only rendering after f12 or resizing window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scheduler, timeline, react-calendar

I'm facing an issue while plotting items array in the timeline calendar. Meanwhile, groups array working fine. Items array also works fine if values are provided manually.

Items only renders after pressing f12 or resize browser window.

**Below is the frontend code ** I checked the backend and it's working fine.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Timeline from 'react-calendar-timeline'
// make sure you include the timeline stylesheet or the timeline will not be styled
import 'react-calendar-timeline/lib/Timeline.css'
import moment from 'moment'
import { getProd } from '../services/frontendRoutes'


export default function Production() {

    const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);


    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await getProd();
            setGroups(data.data.groups);
            const item = data.data.items;
            let itemss = item.map(i => {
                i.start_time = moment(i.start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
                i.end_time = moment(i.end_time, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
                return i;
            })
            setItems(itemss);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                Production
                <Timeline
                    groups={groups}
                    items={items}
                    defaultTimeStart={moment().startOf('year').toDate()}
                    defaultTimeEnd={moment().endOf('year').toDate()}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


/*
const { data } = await getProd();
            setGroups(data.data.groups);
            gruups = data.data.groups
            console.log('Gruups', gruups)
            const item = data.data.items;
            let itemss = item.map(i => {
                i.start_time = moment(i.start_time, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
                i.end_time = moment(i.end_time, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
                return i;
            })
            console.log('Itemms', itemss);
            setItems(itemss);*/
            
            
 //Below is the axios request code to fetch data from backend
 
 import axios from 'axios'
const apiUrl_prod = 'http://localhost:8000/api/prod';
const apiUrl_sub = 'http://localhost:8000/api/sub'
const apiUrl_paint = 'http://localhost:8000/api/paint'
const apiUrl_final = 'http://localhost:8000/api/final'

export function getProd() {
    return axios.get(apiUrl_prod);
}

export function getSub() {
    return axios.get(apiUrl_sub);
}

// export async function getPaint() {
//     try {
//         const res = await axios.get(apiUrl_paint);
//         console.log(res.data)
//     }
//     catch (err) {
//         console.log(err);

//     }
// }

export function getPaint() {
    //console.log('success');
    return axios.get(apiUrl_paint)
}

export function getFinal() {
    return axios.get(apiUrl_final);
}
```

[image: Before pressing f12]

[image: After pressing f12]

Answer (score 0):

I solved with that code:

```
{groups.length!=0 && items.length!=0 && <Timeline
```

[reference link](https://github.com/namespace-ee/react-calendar-timeline/issues/718#issuecomment-585658465)